# before_filter running multiple methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

is it possible to have:

`before_filter :authenticate_user! || :authenticate_admin!`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
before_filter {authenticate_user! || authenticate_admin!}
```

Passing in a proc to the before_filter method, would be the closest to what you have provided in you question.

Comment: authenticate_user! || authenticate_admin! 
does not work. the moment the resource is not user it wont check for the authenticate_admin! and would raise an Unauthorized status.

Answer (score 6):

```
before_filter :do_authentication

def do_authentication
  authenticate_user! || authenticate_admin!
end
```

Answer (score -2):

Since `:authenticate_user!` is a symbol, `:foo == true` is valid. Therefore, your example will always just equate to `before_filter :authenticate_user!`

Try something like (not sure of your setup here..):

```
if method_defined?(:authenticate_user!)
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
else
  before_filter :authenticate_admin!
end
```

If you have both methods defined and want to run `authenticate_user!` then if that returns false, run `authenticate_admin!`, just make one `authenticate!` method that checks for uses/admin and run that `before_filter`.

Comment: `:foo == true` is not true (pun not intended). Check that with irb. You've probably wanted to say ":foo is a trueish value".